# Opening flex application from mail's attachment in iOS

Tags: iphone, apache-flex, ios, ipod

I've read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application) which is really helpful. However I'm trying to open attachments in flex application. Is it possible? Any experience about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, but I've found what I was looking for here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f-5d0f4f25128cc9cd0cb-7ffe.html#WS901d38e593cd1bac6c9d409a12e26b451be-8000

I had to prepare the proper file descriptor. Works fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
<iPhone>
    <InfoAdditions><![CDATA[
        <key>UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend</key>
        <true/>
        <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
        <array>
            <string>1</string>
            <string>2</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
                <array>
                    <string>iconsMobile/app32.png</string>
                    <string>iconsMobile/app128.png</string>
                </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
                <string>File Type Name</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
                <string>Viewer</string>
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
                <string>Owner</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.filename.ext</string>
                <string>com.filename.ext2</string>
                <string>org.gnu.gnu-zip-archive</string>
            </array>
            </dict>
        </array>
    <key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
    <array>
            <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.data</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>File Type Name</string>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.instacoll.mockups.lmp</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <array>
                <string>ext</string>
                <string>ext1</string>
            </array>
            <key>public.mime-type</key>
            <string>application/octet-stream</string>
        </dict>
            </dict>
    </array>
    ]]></InfoAdditions>
    <requestedDisplayResolution>high</requestedDisplayResolution>
</iPhone>
```

Add this to application xml and replace the ext to your extension it will work..
i add this with multiple extension support if want use ext1 also else remove that entry.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can install an app from an email attachment and Flash isn't installed on the iPhone.  So essentially, no, you can't open a Flex app from an email attachment.

Comment: Thanks for answear. I meant opening iOS application which was made using flex framework.

Comment: Ah, now I get it.  You should look at [this link](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-other-apps-within-an-iphone-application.html) for ways to open external apps on iOS.  I *believe* that you can open those applications just like you would try to load a url.  I've never tried it, but it's a start.